# Python + WAMP + Django --> ImportError: No module named os

Tags: python, django, wamp

I've installed WAMPServer (latest). Python 2.6 and Django 1.4 .

Everything looks to be good up until I start running my server. I get Internal Server Error. Apache error log shows the following:

```
[Sun Apr 08 16:11:27 2012] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=1040): Target WSGI script 'C:/wamp/www/testproject/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Apr 08 16:11:27 2012] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=1040): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/wamp/www/testproject/django.wsgi'.
[Sun Apr 08 16:11:27 2012] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Apr 08 16:11:27 2012] [error]   File "C:/wamp/www/testproject/django.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
[Sun Apr 08 16:11:27 2012] [error]     import os, sys  
[Sun Apr 08 16:11:27 2012] [error] ImportError: No module named os
```

I've got all my Environment variables and such set up. Using the Django provided server, it all works. I want to use Apache.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like you need to setup apache to use mod_wsgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can occur when your Python/mod_wsgi installation has been done wrong. Key things to check are:

1. That Python was installed for all users.
2. That Python, Apache and mod_wsgi are all 32 bit or all 64 bit. You cannot mix 32 bit and 64 bit.
3. That mod_wsgi was compiled for the version of Python you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your help. While downloading mod_wsgi, I noticed you were the uploader, haha. It all works now.

Comment: Actually, forgot to highlight that the mod_wsgi.so from mod_wsgi site is only 32 bit. For 64 bit binaries you will need to go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/